Autoccorelation of a Random Process with Rectangular Pulses
I’m working on the same exercise on this link and would like to modify the data related to the sequences
$\mathcal B_k$. Specifically, I’m considering changing the probabilities or values of $\mathcal B_k$ and how this adjustment might affect the calculation of the autocorrelation.

If the $\mathcal B_k$ is 0 or A with the same probability of $\frac 12$;
If the $\mathcal B_k$ still -A or A with the probabilities of $\frac 34$ and $\frac 14$;

My problem for both cases is finding the autocorrelation when:

$|\tau| < T$ and $k\neq k^\prime$
$|\tau| > T$

The autoccorelation function is given by:
\begin{align}
E[\mathcal X(t)\mathcal X(s)] &=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{k^\prime=-\infty}^\infty E[\mathcal B_k \mathcal B_{k^\prime}]E\left[ p\left({t - \mathcal T -kT}\right)p\left({s - \mathcal T -k^\prime T}\right)\right]\end{align}
So how to get the result in both cases?

What is $\tau$? It doesn't appear anywhere except in the bulleted list. As a general hint, I recommend looking at $$E\left[ p\left({t - \mathcal T -kT}\right)p\left({s - \mathcal T -k^\prime T}\right)\right] = \int_0^T p\left({t - u -kT}\right)p\left({s - uT -k^\prime T}\right)\frac 1T ,\mathrm du$$ and proving that the integrand (and hence the integral) has value $0$ for almost all choices of values of $k$ and $k^\prime$
